# React Native CLI hide status bar in landscape mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native

I have a problem, how can I hide a status bar in landscape mode?
In portrait mode its works.

I'm hiding the status bar by either:

```
<StatusBar hidden={true} />
```

or

```
StatusBar.setHidden(true);
```

But when I call my modal screen to show fullscreen mode that statusbar comes back. Why or how can I fix that?

```
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.67.4",
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, Platform, SafeAreaView, StatusBar, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

const STYLES = ['default', 'dark-content', 'light-content'];
const TRANSITIONS = ['fade', 'slide', 'none'];

const App = () => {
  const [hidden, setHidden] = useState(false);
  const [statusBarStyle, setStatusBarStyle] = useState(STYLES[0]);
  const [statusBarTransition, setStatusBarTransition] = useState(TRANSITIONS[0]);

  const changeStatusBarVisibility = () => setHidden(!hidden);

  const changeStatusBarStyle = () => {
    const styleId = STYLES.indexOf(statusBarStyle) + 1;
    if (styleId === STYLES.length) {
      setStatusBarStyle(STYLES[0]);
    } else {
      setStatusBarStyle(STYLES[styleId]);
    }
  };

  const changeStatusBarTransition = () => {
    const transition = TRANSITIONS.indexOf(statusBarTransition) + 1;
    if (transition === TRANSITIONS.length) {
      setStatusBarTransition(TRANSITIONS[0]);
    } else {
      setStatusBarTransition(TRANSITIONS[transition]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar
        animated={true}
        backgroundColor="#61dafb"
        barStyle={statusBarStyle}
        showHideTransition={statusBarTransition}
        hidden={hidden} />
      <Text style={styles.textStyle}>
        StatusBar Visibility:{'\n'}
        {hidden ? 'Hidden' : 'Visible'}
      </Text>
      <Text style={styles.textStyle}>
        StatusBar Style:{'\n'}
        {statusBarStyle}
      </Text>
      {Platform.OS === 'ios' ? (
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>
          StatusBar Transition:{'\n'}
          {statusBarTransition}
        </Text>
      ) : null}
      <View style={styles.buttonsContainer}>
        <Button
          title="Toggle StatusBar"
          onPress={changeStatusBarVisibility} />
        <Button
          title="Change StatusBar Style"
          onPress={changeStatusBarStyle} />
        {Platform.OS === 'ios' ? (
          <Button
            title="Change StatusBar Transition"
            onPress={changeStatusBarTransition} />
        ) : null}
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ECF0F1'
  },
  buttonsContainer: {
    padding: 10
  },
  textStyle: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginBottom: 8
  }
});

export default App;
```

Hope it will help you!

Comment: Okey, but what do You mean? You mean i can hide status bar by adding " <StatusBar
        [...]
        hidden={hidden} />" ? 

If yes, it doesn't work in landscape mode.  Becouse rest of your code it for adding transtitions or styles. Or I don't understand something here?